# ruby on rails ssh connection without giving a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ssh

Currently i'm doing an ssh connection in my code like this:

```
Net::SSH.start( @HOST, @USER, :password => @PASS ) do|ssh|
   @result = ssh.exec!("ls")
   end
```

Now I need to do an SSH connection without giving any password. I was not able to find the exact format to start ssh connection without giving any password.

I have added the SSH keys in authorized key list of the HOST. I remember seeing the below code somewhere on the net when i browsed for ssh without password.

```
Net::SSH.start( @HOST, @USER) do|ssh|
       @result = ssh.exec!("ls")
       end
```

Please correct me if iam wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to point to your private key, not public key:

```
@USER = "me" 
@KEYS = ["my private key here"] 
@HOST = hostname  
Net::SSH.start( @HOST, @USER, :key_data=>@KEYS, :keys_only=>TRUE ) do|ssh|
  @result = ssh.exec!("ls")                 
end
```

and now it does not take the password anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Question: do you know how to automatically accept the rsa host key? (the first time you log onto linux you have to type 'yes' to accept the host key that is exchanged)